# How to use Tokenizer (Keras)? Unable to generate tokens on Character level

Tags: python, tokenize, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

**goal:** vectorizing on character-level

**problem:** output is not a unique number per character/letter, instead all letters are converted to 1

**Question:** What is wrong with my code?

I have a dataframe (df). Where column 'left' and 'right' are codes describing a product and 'Match' whether or not left and right describe the same product.

I use Tokenizer from Keras to vectorize the input on character-level. What I was expecting is the coversion of letters to numbers, instead I receive [1,1,1,1,1.....,1,1]. The underscores do not hold informative value.

Any suggestions what the errors are in my code?

sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'left': ['k2____v72___zal81_f45___hl3___', 'vj43__i1____i1____ixk4__cdo9__'],
                   'right': ['zal81_jy9___v72___qo7___zr6___', 'e95___qto54_bx29__sef9__md40__'],
                   'Match': [ 1,0]})
```

Looking like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
X_train = df['A']
 
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(char_level=True,
                                                  num_words = 500,
                                                 lower = False, # input is already in lower case
                                                 filters='_',
                                                 oov_token=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([X_train])
```

To test and output:

```
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(["g2____v72___zal81_f45___hl3___"])
print(sequences)
print(tokenizer.word_index)
```

Returning:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are passing `X_train` as a list, you should do:

```
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
```

That will produce:

```
[[1, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 11, 7, 2, 2, 2, 12, 13, 14, 3, 2, 15, 4, 16, 2, 2, 2, 17, 9, 10, 2, 2, 2]]
{True: 1, '_': 2, '1': 3, '4': 4, 'i': 5, 'k': 6, '2': 7, 'v': 8, 'l': 9, '3': 10, '7': 11, 'z': 12, 'a': 13, '8': 14, 'f': 15, '5': 16, 'h': 17, 'j': 18, 'x': 19, 'c': 20, 'd': 21, 'o': 22, '9': 23}
```